# Ergodic Markov chains and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, transition-matrix

I just read on wikipedia that a way to check whether a Markov chain is ergodic is to compute the eigenvalues of the transition matrix, and if those are all (except for 1) less than 1, then the chain is ergodic.

But consider the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

It is not ergodic, but the eigenvalues are $(1,0,0,0)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean eigenvectors rather than eigenvalues?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Markov_chains they refer to eigenvalues...

Comment: But eigenvalues are complex numbers not vectors. Am I wrong?

Comment: i have no idea...

Comment: I believe the Wikipedia article is mistaken about that, as well as the statement in the preceding paragraph "Markov's theorem: a Markov chain is ergodic if there is a positive probability to pass from any state to any other state in one step."

Comment: I asked the question also in the wikipedia page and they told me my matrix is not a Markov chain... now I m even more confused ...

Comment: But your Markov chain *is* ergodic: it has a unique absorbing state (state $4$) that is reachable from any other state.

Comment: @Blackbird sorry to revive an old post, but according with the definition on wikipedia the matrix is not ergodic.. but at this point I think the problem is in the definition..

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you're missing is that the columns of a transition/stochastic matrix must sum to 1 (or the rows must sum to 1 for it to be right stochastic).

Comment: I think that the rows (not the columns) must sum to one